# Is there still room for optimization in this part of the code?

Tags: c

```
void HappyTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2100000000; i++) {
        int n = i;
        while (n >= 10) {
            int m = n, sum = 0;
            while (m != 0) {
                int t = m >= 10 ? m % 10 : m;
                sum += t * t;
                m /= 10;
            }
            n = sum;
        }
        //return n == 1 || n == 7;
        //if (i % 10000000 == 0) {
        //  cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

[VS2017 Debug Mode Performance analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M85d.png)

I used the performance analysis tool of vs2017 to get the data in the figure, and found that the performance consumption is mainly % and * operation. 
Is there any room for optimization in this part of the code?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yes. The function has no effect, so `void HappyTest() {}` is a perfectly good optimisation.

Comment: The loop can start at `for (int i=11...`

Comment: My gut feeling tells me there will be overflows with that large final value for `i`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I was afraid too but is 0x7D2B7500 so compatible with _int_ on 32bits

Comment: @bruno, I removed first comment (need to check more). What about overflow of `sum`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie you know as it was said that code does nothing and a normal compiler generates an empty body :)

Comment: @ bruno, look at the commented-out code. Intention is to return/do something.

Comment: The inner loop sums the squares of the digits of `n`. Then this sum is assigned to `n` again. __Q:__ will the sum of the square of the digits of `n` ever become less than `n`? Take 29.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I consider the code as it is, without removing '//' ... but adding the missing '}', else it cannot compile and it is useless to speak about execution ^^ Note also the code in the link is not the same too ...

Comment: @RedaMeskali Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number), but who knows...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes. e.g. 29 is an "unhappy" number: 29 → 85 → *89* → 145 → 42 → 20 → **4** → 16 → 37 → 58 → *89* … While e.g. 139 is "happy": 139 → 91 → 82 → 68 → 100 → 1.

Comment: Assuming the intent is to uncomment the statement `return n == 1 || n == 7` and change the return type of the function to `int`,  the entire body of the function can be optimised to `return 0`.  During the first `for` loop iteration, `i` is `0`, `n` is `0`, so the condition of the first `while` is `false` (or `0`), the `while` loop is ever executed, and the `return` statement returns `0`. This means the question is pointless - the "best" optimisation depends on information not stated in the question, so any viable answer will make assumptions or be opinion-based.  Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: `int t = m >= 10 ? m % 10 : m;` prevents the modulus being taken if it doesn't need to be - at the expense of a pipeline break? Anyway the `cout` shows this isn't C code.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that is the idea. On my system it gives a ~30% run time improvement so it seems a good idea to avoid the unnecessary modulus.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by a minor rewrite of your code - like:

```
int HappyTest()
{
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 210000000; i++) {  // Reduced by a factor 10 compared to OP code
        n = i;
        while (n >= 10) {
            int m = n, sum = 0;
            while (m != 0) {
                int t = m >= 10 ? m % 10 : m;
                sum += t * t;
                m /= 10;
            }
            n = sum;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", HappyTest());
}
```

Running this on my system takes 10.7 seconds.

Your code is about: take a number and calculate the sum of all its digits squared.

So your multiplications are limited to 10 different multiplications, i.e. 0*0, 1*1, ..., 9*9

So one idea for optimization could be to put the results into a table and do a table look-up instead of a multiplication. Like:

```
int mul_tab_10[10] = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81};

int HappyTest()
{
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 210000000; i++) {
        n = i;
        while (n >= 10) {
            int m = n, sum = 0;
            while (m != 0) {
                int t = m >= 10 ? m % 10 : m;
                sum += mul_tab_10[t];
                m /= 10;
            }
            n = sum;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Running this on my system takes 12.9 seconds. So it is **slower**.

But what if we took this one step further? Instead of just using a table with 10 elements we could use a table with 100 elements. Like:

```
int mul_tab_100[100] = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, 50, 65, 82, 4, 5, 8, 13, 20, 29, 40, 53, 68, 85, 9, 10, 13, 18, 25, 34, 45, 58, 73, 90, 16, 17, 20, 25, 32, 41, 52, 65, 80, 97, 25, 26, 29, 34, 41, 50, 61, 74, 89, 106, 36, 37, 40, 45, 52, 61, 72, 85, 100, 117, 49, 50, 53, 58, 65, 74, 85, 98, 113, 130, 64, 65, 68, 73, 80, 89, 100, 113, 128, 145, 81, 82, 85, 90, 97, 106, 117, 130, 145, 162};

int HappyTest()
{
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 210000000; i++) {
        n = i;
        while (n >= 10) {
            int m = n, sum = 0;
            while (m != 0) {
                int t = m >= 100 ? m % 100 : m;  // Notice this change
                sum += mul_tab_100[t];
                m /= 100;                        // Notice this change
            }
            n = sum;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Running this on my system takes 6.9 seconds. So the **performance is improved**.

Taking it one step further (i.e. 1000 elements) results in 5.3 seconds - again a **improvement**.

So yes, you can improve run time performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is room for more efficiency, but I am not sure what the code actually does because it does not look for the repetitive cycles found with happy numbers. However:

- Get rid of the unnecessary `int m`
- You avoided the `m % 10` modulus for values < 10 **but not** the `m / 10` division. The last digit can be computed outside the loop
- Use a cache: you will examine the same values over and over inside the loop (see below).

Modified code, although it wasn't clear due to the missing brace and commented code

```
void HappyTest(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2100000000; i++) {
        int n = i;
        while (n >= 10) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (n >= 10) {       // while(m != 0)
                int t = n % 10;
                n /= 10;
                sum += t * t;
            }
            sum += n * n;           // final digit moved out of loop
            n = sum;
        }
        if(n == 1 || n == 7) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Coming back to the cache idea. Note that on the first parse of a 10-digit number the sum of the squares of its digits cannot be more than `9 * 9 * 10 = 810` (actually less, for a 32-bit `int`) which is fed back into the second parse. So the first `810` numbers can be treated differently - their result is stored in an array. The remaining numbers need only make **one** parse of the digits, and the result can then be looked up.

```
#define LIMIT       2100000000
#define CACHE_SZ    810

void HappyTest(void)
{
    char cached[CACHE_SZ] = { 0 };

    // the first part also sets up the cache
    for (int i = 0; i < CACHE_SZ; i++) {
        int n = i;
        while (n >= 10) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (n >= 10) {       // while(m != 0)
                int t = n % 10;
                n /= 10;
                sum += t * t;
            }
            sum += n * n;           // final digit moved out of loop
            n = sum;
        }
        if(n == 1 || n == 7) {
            //printf("%d\n", i);
            cached[i] = 1;
            results++;
        }
    }

    // the second part continues more simply
    for (int i = CACHE_SZ; i < LIMIT; i++) {
        int n = i;
        int sum = 0;
        // only one parse of the number
        while (n >= 10) { 
            int t = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            sum += t * t;
        }
        sum += n * n;
        // then look it up
        if(cached[sum]) {
            //printf("%d\n", i);
            results++;
        }
    }
}
```

This runs in about 1/3 of the time that your function take (both without the `printf`).

Comment: You could take one step further and avoid parsing each number to calculate the sum: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Suq1GXUDhdNfKk1n